# JS | problems with getContext('2d')

Tags: javascript, html, css

I runned in some problems recentely with the canvas.getContext('2d') method. I tried to declare it as let in the global scope but as empty, and initalise it in a const. But i can't call it outside of that const.
I remember that that worked some time ago, did anything change or whats the problem with my code?

Thanks for any answers!

```js
(() => {

    let request;
    let canvas;
    let ctx;

    const start = document.getElementById("start");
    const menu = document.getElementById("start-menu");

    const init = () => {
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = window.screen.availWidth - (window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth + 20);
        canvas.height = window.screen.availHeight - (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight + 20);

        canvas.id = "animation-panel";

        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
    
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }

    const animate = () => {
        request = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        draw();
    }  

    const draw = () => {
        var playerPosX = 50;
        var playerPosY = 50;
        
        //i want to call the ctx here
        

    }

    init();

    start.addEventListener("click", () => {

        menu.style.display = "none";

        animate();
    })
})()
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#animation-panel {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#start-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 50px 150px 50px 150px;
    background-color: #A758DB;
    display: true;
}

#high-score {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#start {
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 60px; 
    background-color: #A758DB;
    border: 3px solid black;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#start:hover {
    border: 3px solid white;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "start-menu">
            <button id="start">Start</button>
            <p id ="high-score">Your High-Score: 0</p>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was Visual Studio Code. Intellisense just didnt show the completion of my code. I am probably going to switch to Web Storm for my Web Development.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `const` value after init (exclude changing property of object).
In your example all works fine and ctx is available to use in place where you "want to call the ctx". Sorry if I misunderstood the question.

```js
const a = 1;
a = 2; // Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

More about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const.

Comment: Yea, i just figured out it works. Its a problem with VC Intellisense just doesnt show it. Sometimes i really hate VisualCode

Comment: Take a look at WebStorm. Very good development environment. Especially if web development is your main specialty.

Comment: @stax please do not accept this answer if it doesn't solve your issue. Your issue was not caused by the use of const, but by an external problem completely unrelated to this answer. If you wish you could self-answer, that would be better, or even you could delete your question, since it is very unlikely that someone else facing the same problem would ever find this question from search-engines.